# Why <button> doesn't have the margin value set by its container?

Tags: html, css, margin, display

I created this website from Udemy and I wanted to add a refresh button but I can't figure out why it is now working. When I add it inside the "container" class, it doesn't take the **margin** value set by the class, which is **auto**.
I needed to add a specific value of margin: auto for the button itself.

Website: https://williambutacu.github.io/DiceGame/dicee.html

Code:

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
  button{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Refresh Me</h1>
    <button onclick="location.reload();">Refresh Page</button>
</div>
```

github needs to update the css file

Comment: Whata do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

No element has a default `margin` property value of `inherit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to have the same css properties as the container, you'll have to give it the same class.

`button` does not inherit the `margin: auto` from it's parent.

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Refresh Me</h1>
    <button class="container" onclick="location.reload();">Refresh Page</button>
</div>
```

(this is not really something I would do though, I think your solution is good)